Use of converter in Spring LDAP ODM
I am using Spring LDAP 2.4.1.
I would like to use the ODM (Object-Directory Mapping) instead of a AttributesMapper the issue is that one field is a String in XML format. I would like to use something like an XmlAdapter with the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation in JAXB to parse this fied into a java Object. I found an interface: org.springframework.ldap.odm.typeconversion.impl.Converter But I didn't find anything on how to implement a converter in Spring LDAP. Is there a way? Is there a doc somewhere that I missed?

Edit:
I found the javadoc of ConverterManagerFactoryBean but I didn't manage to configure my own converter. I don't understand how to link my converter to the property ref <property name="converter" ref="myTypeConverter" />
